# Check if the value has been the same for x consecutive days

Tags: sql, mariadb

My goal is to get a list of users(uploaders) which have uploaded 0 byte files for 4 consecutive days.

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM file_uploads
JOIN (
    SELECT max(date_added) as latest_date
    FROM file_uploads
    WHERE size = 0
    GROUP BY uploader_id
) as list
```

So in the JOIN I try to get the latest date grouped by uploader where a file is uploaded with the size of 0.

Now I need to check if the size has been 0 for -4 consecutive days since the latest_date, but that is what I can't figure out. Can I check it with a WHERE statement or do I need to do an IF statement or something else.

This is an example of the table I'm working with: https://ibb.co/Sf3RFSk

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the desired result is given in the first sentence. "My goal is to get a list of users..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one row per date, you can filter by the maximum date and then count the number of rows that are `0` for each `uploader_id`:

```
select uploader_id
from file_uploads fu
where fu.date_uploaded >= (select max(fu2.date_uploaded) - interval 3 day
                           from file_uploads fu2
                           where fu2.uploader_id = fu.uploader_id
                          ) and
      fu.size = 0
group by uploader_id
having count(*) = 4;
```

Comment: This doesn't return the right value for me. Only returns uploader_id 15, which isn't correct. It should also return uploader_id 1.

Comment: @Merdin . . . You want the latest *per `uploader_id`* not overall.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I also want to check if there are no files uploaded for 4 consecutive days?

Comment: @Merdin . . . I think you should ask a new question and be clear about exactly what you mean.  Any four days or the most recent?  File size of 0 or missing or both?